# Disable actions in the Actions menu on the Purchase Order screen

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to disable and enable the highlighted actions inside the action menu on the Purchase Orders screen, I have tried using

```
`Base.Actions["complete"].SetEnabled(false);` and `Base.complete.SetVisible(false);`
```

but that does not work.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Purchase Orders screen uses the POOrderEntry graph.  You will want to override the POOrder RowSelected event.  Next, you want to use SetEnabled and SetVisible on the complete action directly.

```
#region POOrder_RowSelected
protected virtual void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseEvent)
{
    baseEvent(sender, e);

    Base.complete.SetEnabled(false);
    Base.complete.SetVisible(false);

}
#endregion
```

Comment: Check for automation steps to see if it is being handled there and overriding your code.  Also, you might try removing via permissions if you don't want this action under any circumstance.

Comment: I managed a work around. I found that keeping the document on Hold keeps the actions disabled, and I can force the Document to stay on Hold until other things have happened.